# Generate real Server URL (not localhost)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, urlhelper

**Hi,**

Im using the following to generate full URL :

```
urlHelper.Action("Detail", "Ad", null, "http") + "?id=" + adId.ToString();
```

This will however return a localhost URL even when the webpage is placed on a public server (www.mywebpage.com)?

Im using ASP.NET MVC 2

**BestRegards**

Comment: Try searching your codebase to see if you've got any references to your localhost URL lingering in config files, global.asax.cs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suddenly started to work, I dont know why it did not work at first.